# Validation of Viewstate MAC failed (Shared hosting Plesk)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, plesk, viewstate, shared-hosting

[image]I am using plesk'shared hosting  server to host my website. Constantly getting ViewState MAC failed error

Plesk won't be able to provide any Machine Key. As it is shared hosting.

I have also attached the screenshot. please help.

Earlier This issue was coming in one page only. I have resolve it by converting it to JavaScript and ajax call in order to Stop AutoPostBack.

But now this is coming in many pagaes.

Answer (score 0):

Add following link in your web.config file.

Above line should be included within section.

OR

if you don't want this solution to implemented on project level then you can add these attribute to the page(Top most line of HTML view) directive of the page which is creating issue.

That means you have to add enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" in page directive.